# Nagios - Get status of a single service on multpile hosts

Tags: linux, bash, nagios

I have a Nagios box installed and it monitors 342 services at the moment.

One of those service checks is for System Up Time. When 30 days lapses, I have it configured to send CRITICAL alarms....Time to REBOOT!

I click on my services link and check each one individually to see what the system up time is; on each Host.

Does anyone think there is a script I could run in a terminal to check only SYSTEM UP TIME for all host's? That way I can get a report of them everyday without have to go line by line to check them?

Just curious.

Thanks for looking everyone!

Comment: You might want to take a step back and ask why your machine needs to be rebooted after only 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can put python or bash script on each host that says if the machine more 30 days up -> reboot.

You can write some script on your local macine that will access each host once per day and will check uptime of each host and make reboot if needed, but at this way you will need to create ssh accees to each host.

Comment: The whole system is up a going. After 30 days it does alarm.  I just want to generate a script that echos the system uptime on each host. Maybe I didn't ask the right question?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to each host?

Comment: I have ssh access to my Nagios. Each Host is running Nagios Service Plugins

Comment: Ok. If i understand correct you have one nagios machine that connects to your windows hosts that runs nagios plugins and check for uptime.

Comment: You can write a script that will run the nagios plugin and check for the output. I think you need to find this plugin on you nagios machine and try to run manualy. After you will see the output you will understand how to calculate the uptime?

Comment: You also will need to create some file with all your host

Comment: Thats right. I think I am just going to write a BASH script to run this for me. But I am curious of what you have in mind.

Comment: That's what I was going to do. I wasn't sure if there was something special in the nagios-cli

Comment: You can write a script in python - it shold be easy.. I think the plugin that you need is /var/lib/nagios or /etc/nagios directory.

Comment: Try to find check_uptime plugin